# Terraform - ASGs with Mixed Instance Policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, autoscaling, terraform-provider-aws, infrastructure-as-code

I am using AWS with Terraform to spin up infra, but specifically I'm having issues spinning up an ASG with a Mixed Instance Policy. I am trying to spin up an ASG where by one instance will always be on-demand and the rest spots (all of the same type), on the face of it this looks easy but Ive been trying for a while and keep hitting various errors. Here's what I'm currently using:

```
 resource "aws_launch_template" "lt" {
   name_prefix            = "danny_test-"
   vpc_security_group_ids = [
     "${module.sec_groups.security_group_id_common}",
     "${module.sec_groups.security_group_id_ssh}",
     "${module.sec_groups.security_group_id_web}"
   ]
   image_id               = "${module.core_ami.core_ami_id}"
   instance_type          = "t2.small"
   key_name               = "${var.ssh_privkey_name}"
   user_data              = "${base64encode(data.template_file.common_user_data.rendered)}"

   iam_instance_profile {
     name = "${module.infradev_remote_state.iam_profile_updater_id}"
   }

   lifecycle {
     create_before_destroy = true
   }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "asg" {
  name                      = "danny_test"
  vpc_zone_identifier       = ["${split(",", module.environment.private_subnet_ids)}"]
  #launch_configuration      = "${aws_launch_configuration.lc.name}"
  min_size                  = "0"
  max_size                  = "1"
  desired_capacity          = "1"
  health_check_grace_period = "600"
  health_check_type         = "EC2"

  launch_template {
    id = "${aws_launch_template.lt.id}"
  }

  mixed_instances_policy {
    instances_distribution {
      on_demand_base_capacity = "1"
    }
  }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Error: aws_autoscaling_group.asg: "mixed_instances_policy.0.launch_template": required field is not set
```

According to the documentation **launch_template** is optional there. I have tried setting this but it just goes down a rabbit hole of supposedly optional settings some of which I simply don't want to set (like overrides).

What is the correct way to achieve what I'm after? Either way it looks like the docs are at least partially wrong based on the above...

Comment: were you able to fix that.In my case no Error but none of instance is spot instance and all are on-demand.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation appears to be wrong because it's set as a [`Required` field in the actual code](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/5b8ed28c7413fc297542bcff1da6f0cf5488270d/aws/resource_aws_autoscaling_group.go#L148):

```golang
        "mixed_instances_policy": {
            Type:     schema.TypeList,
            Optional: true,
            MaxItems: 1,
            Elem: &schema.Resource{
                Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
                    # ...
                    "launch_template": {
                        Type:     schema.TypeList,
                        Required: true,
                        MinItems: 1,
                        MaxItems: 1,
```

The [`aws_autoscaling_group` resource docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html#mixed-instances-policy) show a useful example which includes the optional overrides you mentioned:

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "example" {
  name_prefix   = "example"
  image_id      = "${data.aws_ami.example.id}"
  instance_type = "c5.large"
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "example" {
  availability_zones = ["us-east-1a"]
  desired_capacity   = 1
  max_size           = 1
  min_size           = 1

  mixed_instances_policy {
    launch_template {
      launch_template_specification {
        launch_template_id = "${aws_launch_template.example.id}"
      }

      override {
        instance_type = "c4.large"
      }

      override {
        instance_type = "c3.large"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

These overrides are in fact optional as shown in [the code](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/5b8ed28c7413fc297542bcff1da6f0cf5488270d/aws/resource_aws_autoscaling_group.go#L178-L189):

```golang
                                "override": {
                                    Type:     schema.TypeList,
                                    Optional: true,
                                    Elem: &schema.Resource{
                                        Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
                                            "instance_type": {
                                                Type:     schema.TypeString,
                                                Optional: true,
                                            },
                                        },
                                    },
                                },
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the case that the overrides are optional, if I remove them from the example I get this error: `aws_autoscaling_group.example: Error creating AutoScaling Group: ValidationError: The number of LaunchTemplateOverrides must be between 2 and 20.`

Comment: have you gotten this override to work? it aalways creates  min number of the first override, despite what weighting you give